# Post Apocalyptic Sci-fi Movie. Female character has her jaw replaced with a cyborg one

Tags: story-identification, movie, robots, post-apocalyptic

I've been trying for a while to find a post-apocalyptic scifi movie from the 90s(?) that had a scene where one of the characters has had her jaw and voice box replaced with cyborg ones (not visible).

In one of the scenes she, with her friend, visits the guy who carried out the surgery (dodgy looking place). Using a remote control he makes her mouth open and moan, somewhat against her will, almost jestfully. Very bizarre.

Comment: This one has very evocative details, but I'm having no luck so far. Sounds a bit like a *Lexx* plotline...